# Which View implementation handles JSPs in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In the SpringMVC documentation I see this for **AbstractView**:

```
    Direct Known Subclasses:
    AbstractExcelView, AbstractFeedView, 
    AbstractJackson2View, AbstractJExcelView, 
AbstractPdfView, AbstractUrlBasedView, 
AbstractXlsView, MarshallingView
```

Which implementation handles regular JSP Views?

The reason for my question is that I want to extend SpringMVC's JSP View, to support a Read-Only mode for a form. The regular view would be the normal JSP, but a Read-Only View would be an extension of the JSP where all fields are converted to labels, i.e. they can't be modified.

Any advice on this approach appreciated.

Comment: JSPs are handled by container

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/JstlView.html

Comment: And how would I specify which View implementation I want to use when returning a ModelAndView? In both cases it's a JSP, but in one case, it's a Custom View where all the fields are read-only.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is you need to get a JSF component root, iterate over all elements, find input fields and replace them with non-input - labels instead?

JSP does not 'like' modifying it's components at runtime. In `JSF` I could suggest you implement a `TagHandler` to modify the component tree based on some parameter returned in the View Model.

In your case - a simple solution would be to either disable inputs based on parameter value

```
<h:inputText value="${inputValue}" disabled="${formDisabled}" />
```

or render different inputs based on parameter value

```
<c:if test="${formDisabled}">
   <div><h:outputText value="${inputValue}" />
</c:if>
<c:if test="${!formDisabled}">
   <h:inputText value="${inputValue}" />
</c:if>
```